# Running a TCPListener while my program opens a form

Tags: c#, forms, tcp

My program starts a TCPListener when I click a button.
Before it opens the TCPListener, it opens a new window.
I want the program to construct the items in the window while the TCPListener is running, aka I need the TCPListener to run in 'the background'.
I'm thinking I need to use threading but I'm not sure how exactly.

Right now basically:

1. Opens the form
2. Runs the TCPListener forever
3. Freezes the form window before it even constructs anything because it is waiting for the TCP Listener to finish. The while loop in the TCP Listener is probably wrong as well. I wish it to keep accepting data.

Here's the code for the method the button runs. The openForm method is also in the same form as the button is.

```
    private void openForm()
    {
        if (!textBox1.Text.Equals("") && !textBox2.Text.Equals("") && !textBox3.Text.Equals("") && !textBox4.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            string fornavn = textBox1.Text;
            string efternavn = textBox2.Text;
            string medarbejdernr = textBox3.Text;
            string organisation = textBox4.Text;
            Form f = new Form1(fornavn, efternavn, medarbejdernr, organisation, this);
            f.Show();
            this.Visible = false;
            Listener listen = new Listener();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Du skal angive noget i alle felter", "Fejl", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

And here's my TCP Listener class.

```
class Listener
{
    const int PORT_NO = 5000;
    const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
    string dataReceived;

    public Listener()
    {
        //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
        IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Parse(SERVER_IP);
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAdd, PORT_NO);
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            listen(listener);
        }
    }
    private void listen(TcpListener listener)
    {

        //---incoming client connected---
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

        //---get the incoming data through a network stream---
        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

        //---read incoming stream---
        int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

        //---convert the data received into a string---
        dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        MessageBox.Show(dataReceived +" har fået et anfald mkay", "Patient har fået anfald mkay", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        //---write back the text to the client---

        client.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Start it in separate thread or make it asynchronous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several ways you can do this - I enjoy using `System.Threading.Task`

```
 private void openForm()
    {
        if (!textBox1.Text.Equals("") && !textBox2.Text.Equals("") && !textBox3.Text.Equals("") && !textBox4.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            string fornavn = textBox1.Text;
            string efternavn = textBox2.Text;
            string medarbejdernr = textBox3.Text;
            string organisation = textBox4.Text;
            Form f = new Form1(fornavn, efternavn, medarbejdernr, organisation, this);
            f.Show();
            this.Visible = false;
            Listener listen = null;
            var taskListener = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                listen = new Listener());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Du skal angive noget i alle felter", "Fejl", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

of course in this case the listen object will fall out of scope as soon as the `openForm()` method exits. So you'll probably want to change the scope of the Listener object to be outside of that method.

Could also use a [background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Or a create your own [thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Here is the MSDN on [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT COMPLETE EXAMPLE**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using(var f = new Form2())
            {
                f.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
}
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public const string SERVER_IP = "192.168.5.1";
        public const int PORT_NO = 3999;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Listener());
        }

        private void ExecuteSecure(Action a)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
                BeginInvoke(a);
            else
                a();
        }

        private void Listener()
        {

            //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
            IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Parse(SERVER_IP);
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAdd, PORT_NO);
            listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                listen(listener);
            }
        }

        private void listen(TcpListener listener)
        {

            //---incoming client connected---
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            //---get the incoming data through a network stream---
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

            //---read incoming stream---
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

            //---convert the data received into a string---
            var dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            //we are listening on a different thread so we cannot show a msgbox directly.
            ExecuteSecure(() => MessageBox.Show(dataReceived + " har fået et anfald mkay", "Patient har fået anfald mkay", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error));
            //---write back the text to the client---

            client.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly a thread task does.
What do you mean that the listen object will 'fall out of scope'?

Comment: @MathiasSiigNørregaard A task is a method for running operations Async - and it is quite easy to use. And here is a blurb on scope (link below)

When that method (openForm()) exits you will no longer be able to access the Listener object. If you declare the variable outside of the method in the class as private then it will not fall out of scope

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)

Comment: Ok. So my first form opens the next form through openForm()
When the next form closes, the entire program closes. So it doesn't really matter at all - I guess?
But it any case, the program doesn't work even with the var taskListener

Comment: @MathiasSiigNørregaard if the form you are opening is using the TCPListener then you should probably declare the variable listener on that form. Also I could be wrong but it seems that you would want to use the second form as a Modal. There are also several other things you'll need to do. For example if the Listener needs to interact with the UI Thread (ie. display message boxes) you'll need to create delegates to invoke those actions. You cannot(shouldnot) interact with a UI component directly without invoking your actions.

Comment: Thanks @Wjdavis5 . I don't understand your answer - yet. I'll look your comment, because I have to learn it.
As for your answer itself, it works. Thanks a lot man.